# Where to check the index that is configured from SXA Search API?

Tags: sxa, content-search, azure-search

When I request the url https://mydomain/sxa/search/results?q=test, below is the response

> {"TotalTime":259,"CountTime":211,"QueryTime":38,"Signature":null,"Index":"sitecore_sxa_web_index","Count":0,"Results":[]}

There are no index entries on the field 'Indexes' in the Settings/Site item. After updating the item with key-value pair master/* - sitecore_master_index also, getting the same response. Where else this setting would have been changed?

Answer (score 5):

You have probably not done last step of installation guide for SXA installations and that is to add two SXA specific Solr cores.

SXA Cores / Indexes are defined in `$path_to_your_instance\App_Config\Modules\SXA\Z.Foundation.Overrides`.

To configure and populate cores for Solr, follow these steps:

### 1. Create Solr Cores

Navigate to your Solr folder and copy two times “{YourSitecoreInstanceName}_master_index” folder e.g. “C:\Solr\solr721\solr-7.2.1\server\solr”:

[image]

Rename newly copied folders as “{YourSitecoreInstanceName}_sxa_master_index” and “{YourSitecoreInstanceName}_sxa_web_index”:

[image]

Navigate to both new folders and remove data subfolder and core.properties file as highlighted here:

[image]

At the end you should leave only conf subfolder under both “{YourSitecoreInstanceName}_sxa_master_index” and “{YourSitecoreInstanceName}_sxa_web_index” folders like this:

[image]

Open Solr admin UI in your browser e.g. https://solr:8983/solr/

Click on Core Admin (1) in left menu and then click on Add Core (2) button with green plus as shown below. Specify “{YourSitecoreInstanceName}_sxa_master_index” in name and instanceDir fields (3) and hit Add Core button (4). Do the same also for {YourSitecoreInstanceName}_sxa_web_index:

[image]

Open `$path_to_your_instance\App_Config\Modules\SXA\Z.Foundation.Overrides` file in your text editor and change core parameters highlighted below to your newly created cores in Solr to each index accordingly (mind highlighted values for each master/web index):

[image]

### 2. Populate Solr Managed Schema for SXA indexes

From Launchpad, open Control Panel:

[image]

Open Populate Solr Managed Schema (1) from Indexing section, select only SXA related indexes highlighted below (2) and click Populate button (3):

[image]

This is desired outcome:

[image]

### 3. Rebuild SXA indexes

From Launchpad, open Control Panel:

[image]

Open Indexing Manager (1) from Indexing section, select only SXA related indexes highlighted below (2) and click Rebuild button (3):

[image]

This is the desired outcome:

[image]

That’s it!

Take a look on my detailed installation steps guide for Sitecore SXA 1.8: https://tothecore.sk/2018/11/29/sitecore-sxa-1-8-installation-guide-for-development-machine/