# SXA Facet Filtering wrong index

Tags: sxa, search-facet

I have a custom index for my tenant and I configured  custom indexes on Sitegrouping to be used by our sites.

On the Search page I have Checkbox filter, Search Box and Search results components .

On search results component I see next api calls :

```
/sxa/search/results/?l=sv-SE&s={01EF90DA-7A77-4F1E-8A1B-81A57C1E7EC2}&itemid={157D1D96-9BD0-4938-8139-E03BF692FD2C}&sig=&autoFireSearch=true&v={5CAA9B1D-6A6F-4639-8F2D-C217326B8521}&p=100
```

where is used my custom index:

```
{TotalTime":608,"CountTime":11,"QueryTime":594,"Signature":null,"Index":"mycustom_web_index","Count":794,"Results"...
```

On the checklist filter component is calling next api:

```
/sxa/search/facets/?f=producttype&s={01EF90DA-7A77-4F1E-8A1B-81A57C1E7EC2}&l=sv-SE&sig=
```

but this api call is using default sxa index

```
{"TotalTime":25,"QueryTime":23,"Signature":null,"Index":"sitecore_sxa_web_index","Facets":[{"Key":"producttype","Name":"ItemType","Values":[]}]}
```

How can I used my custom index inside checkbox filter component.

I checked this question : [Where to check the index that is configured from SXA Search API?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/17172/where-to-check-the-index-that-is-configured-from-sxa-search-api) but it didn't help me.

Comment: What SXA version are you using?

Comment: I am using Sxa 1.7

Comment: That is quite old version. At the latest code it works fine, we have separate service which is resolving an index for the site. I will need to check how this was looking in the past on 1.7. Will check that for you tomorrow!

Comment: thank you Dawid. I guess I have to check Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Services.IndexResolver

Answer (score 1):

We recently faced same issue on **Sitecore 9.0.2** & **SXA 1.7.1**.

when contacted the Support team, they did mention it is a bug and provided patch for it.

Reference number: **255689**

Patch link for SXA 1.7.1 https://sitecore.app.box.com/s/izuju5sf8z8zup9ixnut72gmwl38dlx1

Note: *This is fixed on **SXA 1.8.1***
https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Accelerator/18/Sitecore%20Experience%20Accelerator%20181/Release%20Notes